# force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8) in one central location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

I am building a rails app. I have options to export to Word.

When I append **.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)** , it works fine.

Is there a way to write this in one central place instead of specifying it in all the places?

Comment: What's your ruby and Rails version?

Comment: Rails - 4.2 & Ruby - 2.3

Comment: “When I append `.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)`”—append _where_?

Comment: Ruby > 2.0.0 interprets all source files as utf-8, so not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: object.attribute.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8) in the .haml file

Comment: @Christian-G It does not support characters that are non-english

Comment: are these objects coming from your database? If so the. having to use force_encoding suggests a configuration issue with the db connection or bad data in your database (or both)